# how can I change order in vectors in Matlab

Tags: matlab, vector

I have a vector

```
H  =
 0
 0
 0
 0
 0
 0
 0
 0
 0
 0
 0
 0
 0
 0
 0
 0
 0
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
```

I want it to be like

```
      H= 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1......
```

I tried with H(:) but it wont work, there is 17 zeros and 16 ones is that maybe a problem?

Comment: What do you want, go from row-vector to column vector? If so, it's H=H'; . If you want to altern '0's and '1's rather than having them ordered, H(:) is definitely not an answer and it really makes your question confusing.

Comment: I suspect you just want to transpose your matrix. As Wli said, you can do H' or transpose(H).

Comment: thank you for reply, I do not want to transpose row to column I want to change for example H=[0 0 0 0 1 1 1] to H=[0 1 0 1 0 1 0]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to alternate elements:

```
H2 = H;
H2([1:2:end,2:2:end])=H;
```

**Explanation:**

`[1:2:end,2:2:end]`, as long as H2 is the same length as H, creates a series of indices which are also of the same length of vector H.  If you call `2:2:end` and `end` (the last element) is odd, it is equivalent to `2:2:(end-1)`, so we don't need to worry about having the `end` element in twice.

For your vector this comes out as `[1,3,5...,33,2,4,6,...,32]`

Then, for each element of H, we assign it to the element of H2 represented by that index vector.  That is, the second line tells MATLAB we want `H2(1) = H(1)`, `H2(3) = H(2)`, and so on.

Comment: thank you for reply,  I want to change for example H=[0 0 0 0 1 1 1] to H=[0 1 0 1 0 1 0] when I do what you told me I get   H2=([1:2:end,2:2:end])=H
 H2=([1:2:end,2:2:end])=H
                       |
Error: The expression to the left of the equals sign is not a valid target for an assignment.

Comment: You have an additional `=` in there.

Comment: Seems to do the trick as well, If you don't mind overwriting the input it can just be a oneliner: `H([1:2:end,2:2:end])=H`

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
V = H;
V(1:2:end) = H(1:ceil(end/2));
V(2:2:end) = H(ceil(end/2)+1:end);
```

Should work for both odd and even length of `H`.

Of course the easier way to create your vector in this specific case would be:

```
V = H*0;
V(2:2:end)=1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you always have en even number of elements, like in your example :

> h = [0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1]' ;

then this should do the trick:

```
%// add 1 element to have an even number of values  
h(end+1) = NaN ;  
%// perform a reshape / transpose / reshape operation  
h2 = reshape( reshape(h,[],2)' , [] , 1 ) ;  %'
%// remove the last element  
h2(end) = [] ;
```

Answer (score -1):

YOu can use H * eye ( H.lenght), but you need to know the number of rows vector H has.

Comment: I think there is something wrong here. `H * eye ( length(H))` just produces `H` again.